# How to write a function to set nobreakindent when using the Pencil plugin?

Tags: indentation

I'm trying to get the [Pencil](https://github.com/reedes/vim-pencil) plugin to run with the `noautoindent` and `nobreakindent` settings. This is what I've tried in my init.vim:

```
+ 201 function! s:pencil_enter()
+ 202     set nobreakindent
+ 203     set noautoindent
+ 204 endfunction
+ 209 autocmd! User PencilEnter nested call <SID>pencil_enter()
```

It doesn't work though. Whenever I do `:Pencil`, all the indenting in my text file continues to get messed up (breakindent).

What might be wrong with the function? If I do it manually with the file open `:set nobreakindent`, it works fine.

Comment: You probably want `setlocal`; what is the output (after `:Pencil`) of `:verbose setlocal breakindent?`

Comment: It didn't produce any output when I did the verbose option. I also tried setlocal in the function and that didn't make a difference either.

Comment: There should be output---note the question mark was part of the command, not part of my asking a question

Comment: Ah! With the question mark, the output indicates "breakindent" and it was Last set from ~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-pencil/autoload/pencil.vim line 283

Comment: Ok, so either your autocommand isnt running, or they’re overriding it. Why is there a bang on autocmd?

Comment: I don't know exactly how vim functions work. I used another function I found as a model for this one so I don't know why there's a bang on function or on autocmd. But I tried removing them and it made no difference.

Comment: Check the help (:help :autocmd, for example). Generally you put autocommands in augroup, and you dont put bang on autocmd except to remove them.